# Android: ListView with RelativeLayout -> NullReference

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout, android-viewholder

I'm trying to implement a ListView relative layout using a ViewHolder. In getView(), I'm running into a NullReference. I've modeled the code after an example I found here on Stack Overflow. Here's the code:

```
private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ToDoItem toDoItem = mItems.get(position);

    if (convertView==null){
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false);

        RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);

        mViewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.title));
        mViewHolder.cbStatus = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
        mViewHolder.tvPriority = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priority);
        mViewHolder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }else{
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    --->mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());
    mViewHolder.tvPriority.setText(toDoItem.getPriority().toString());
    mViewHolder.tvDate.setText(toDoItem.getDate().toString());
    mViewHolder.cbStatus.setChecked(false);

    if (toDoItem.getStatus().toString() == "DONE") mViewHolder.cbStatus.setChecked(true);


    final TextView titleView = mViewHolder.tvTitle;
    final CheckBox statusView = mViewHolder.cbStatus;
    final TextView priorityView = mViewHolder.tvPriority;
    final TextView dateView = mViewHolder.tvDate;

    itemLayout.addView(titleView);
    itemLayout.addView(statusView);
    itemLayout.addView(priorityView);
    itemLayout.addView(dateView);

    return convertView;
```

The NullReference is thrown on the line following the closing bracket of the

**if (convertView == null)**

and is marked with ---->

I've tried to assign different entities to the ViewHolder with little success. I'd appreciate any help anyone has to offer. Thanks in advance!

Markb

Comment: The null reference is referencing to mViewHolder or toDoItem? This question may resolt your doubts. Try testing every object if is null. In my opinion, is a "ToDoItem" object null reference, but confirm that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that bit of info: toDoItem is correctly populated. The null is on mViewHolder.

Comment: Let me further refine my last response: mViewHolder exists, but the tvTitle field contains a null (as do all of the other TextView fields in the object). Makes sense to me since all that's happened up to that point has been to construct the elements of the view holder. The view holder structure is there, as is the completely populated toDoItem. why can I not assign a legitimate value to the mViewHolder field?

Comment: This null expcetion, comes when convertView is null or with convertVIew != null? I recommend you to put convertView.setTag(mViewHolder); at the end of method. Why?

Answer (score 0):

`toDoItem` Could be null as well if that object in the list is null.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that bit of info: toDoItem is correctly populated. The null is on mViewHolder.

Comment: You mViewHolder should be inside the `getView` method. Try changing this and see if it changes the outcome.

Comment: No change. Scoping the view holder at the module level only makes it visible everywhere in the class, there's no functional consideration.